# Select sub string from column based on another column in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to get sub string from Country column, based on UserCountry column.

This is my current output, Based on my query.

[image]

Now what I want is, If userCountry column value is **Singapore** then In country column should have only **Singapore**.

So My expected output in country column for these 2 result should be

- in first row: Singapore
- in second row: Malaysia

Country column have `,` separated value.

This is my query

```
select PU.Email,PUC.DisplayName UserCountry
    ,STUFF((SELECT  ',' + IIF(C.DisplayName IS NOT NULL,C.DisplayName,CTC.TargetingId)
            FROM CampaignTargeting CTC
            LEFT JOIN  Country C On CTC.TargetingId = C.Id
            WHERE CTC.CampaignId =Camp.Id and CTC.TypeName='Country'
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS Country 
    ,STUFF((SELECT  ',' + IIF(P.DisplayName IS NOT NULL, P.DisplayName,CTP.TargetingId)
            FROM  CampaignTargeting CTP
            LEFT JOIN Profession P On CTP.TargetingId = P.Id
            WHERE  CTP.CampaignId =Camp.Id and CTP.TypeName='Profession'
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS Profession
    ,STUFF((SELECT  ',' + IIF(S.DisplayName IS NOT NULL, S.DisplayName,CTS.TargetingId)
            FROM CampaignTargeting CTS
            LEFT JOIN Specialty S On CTS.TargetingId = S.Id
            WHERE CTS.CampaignId =Camp.Id and CTS.TypeName='Specialty'
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS Specialty
    ,STUFF((SELECT  ',' + IIF(SS.DisplayName IS NOT NULL,SS.DisplayName,CTSS.TargetingId)
            FROM CampaignTargeting CTSS 
            LEFT JOIN SubSpecialty SS  On CTSS.TargetingId = SS.Id 
            WHERE CTSS.CampaignId =Camp.Id and CTSS.TypeName='SubSpecialty' 
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS SubSpecialty
 FROM Campaign Camp
    LEFT JOIN PointsTransaction PT ON PT.ReferenceId=Camp.Id and PT.Points > 0
    LEFT JOIN PointUser PU ON PU.Id=PT.PointUserId
    LEFT JOIN Country PUC on PU.CountryId=PUC.Id
 WHERE Camp.Id='8bd948c9-a597-480b-8772-815f2b31c850'
 GROUP BY Camp.Id,PU.Email,PUC.DisplayName
```

I'm using MS SQL server 2012.

Comment: then why to use Stuff statement directly use Country Column as user country @amit

Comment: please avoid photo during ask question. Here, I've network issue. So you lose extraordinary answer.  Let us know your IP.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of finding the substring, you could directly use the UserCountry column value in Country column, if both need to be the same. Hope it helps.

Comment: the same have posted in comments @aparna

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `case` statement:

```
SELECT . . . ,
       (CASE WHEN PUC.DisplayName = 'Singapore' THEN 'Singapore'
             ELSE STUFF((SELECT  ',' + IIF(C.DisplayName IS NOT NULL,C.DisplayName, CTC.TargetingId)
                         FROM CampaignTargeting CTC LEFT JOIN
                              Country C 
                              ON CTC.TargetingId = C.Id
                         WHERE CTC.CampaignId = Camp.Id and CTC.TypeName = 'Country'
                         FOR XML PATH('')
                        ), 1, 1, ''
                       )
        END) AS Country,
       . . .
```